# Do I need to set an Entitlements.plist file to my target to make Push Notifications work?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, code-signing, entitlements

I'm having a lot of problems trying to configure Push Notifications that I don't understand and I explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309934/submitting-a-binary-for-beta-testing-missing-push-notification-entitlement). I think I did all I have to do: creating APNS certificates, enabling Push services in App ID, and creating associated provisioning profiles with Push Notifications enabled. All seems to be ok at my Member Center. But this does not work in Xcode, Xcode is not showing me any aps entitlement anywhere... Could it be because in Build Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Entitlements I have nothing? What should I put there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's an excellent guide on how to do this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html

Answer (score 5):

The direct answer is Yes.

If you are using push notifications then it has to be added in Entitlements.plist or else app can't be installed in latest iOS versions.

[image]

Other than *enabling push notification in your provisioning profile* you have to enable it on *xcode capabilities* which deals with Entitlements.plist

Comment: I am facing a different issue, when i enable the “push notification” in capabilities and try to install the app in device its not getting installed. It shows an alert “unable to download”. I have push notifications enabled for my app id and have an updated provisioning profile which includes push notifications. Is it really necessary to enable this for receiving notifications?

Comment: When i enable the push notification in entitlements, and take a build its not getting installed in the phone. Whereas when i uncheck it and build its getting installed. I checked my provisioning profile and it has push notifications included in it. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: If you look into console logs it'll give you the root cause of it.

Comment: Got the error below in Console.    0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application. Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

Comment: I can see that Push Notifications are enabled in my profile. Not sure why it is showing an error ?

Comment: Finally found out the issue. I was trying to build the application with "distribution profile" and the "aps-environment" was set to "development" there. If we are using distribution profile we have to set that to "production". Right click on the entitlements.plist and open with Xcode where we can edit it. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848389/xamarin-ios-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements?rq=1also.