# Xamarin.iOS: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I've recently added notifications (**FCM**) to an iOS app developed with **Xamarin.iOS**.
When I try to install on a device in release - both on iPad and iPhone - the installation fails.
All the similar questions I've found are related to native development. I tried to regenerate provisioning profiles removing and adding again push notification permission but it doesn't work. I'm quite sure it's a problem with entitlements.plist but I cannot see the error.

Reading device log I can see:

J:2688602321590689122,I:5638904815675342255#[]: Failed to install 
J:2688602321590689122,I:5638904815675342255#[]: Install failed after error:

0x16df47000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 147: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.uANw57/extracted/Payload/Wine.iOS.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)

installd(MobileSystemServices)[42] : 0x16df47000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was easy and the problem was really in Entitlements.plist.

Trying to install the app directly from Xcode it returned this error:

[image]

I didn't notice that inside Entitlements.plist there was:

```
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
```

It was enough to change 'development' with 'production'.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling to solve it and it was very simple. Just like you I've tried everything, regenerating all profiles, etc. Thanks, man!

Comment: Me too, saved a lot of wasted time. Thanks